# How to add custom data on exception handling using azure webjobs SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have a simple Azure Function which returns to a queue:

```
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    [return: Queue("%ReturnQueue%")]
    public async Task<string> Run([QueueTrigger("%RequestQueue%")] string msg, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some dependency calls   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dic.Add("Id", someId);
            dic.Add("CustomData", cusomData);

            _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex, dic);
        }
    }
```

I obviously get a compilation error saying that not all code paths returns a value. 
The problem is that if I add a `throw` at the end of the catch block the `Azure Functions` runtime replicate the excpetion on the appinsights portal. How can I add custom data to my exceptions like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Exception type:

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string CustomData {get;set;}
   public Exception RootException {get;set;}

   public MyCustomException(string id, string customData, Exception ex)
   {
      Id = id;
      CustomData = customData;
      RootException = ex;
   }
}


private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    [return: Queue("%ReturnQueue%")]
    public async Task<string> Run([QueueTrigger("%RequestQueue%")] string msg, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some dependency calls   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //var dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            //dic.Add("Id", someId);
            //dic.Add("CustomData", cusomData);

            var customEx = new MyCustomException(someId, cusomData, ex);

            _telemetryClient.TrackException(customEx);
        }
        finally
        {
             return "";
        }
    }
```

PS: inside MyCustomException you can actually have Dictionary rather than string properties.

Comment: You will get an error with this code saying that not all code paths returns a value

Comment: sorry it was not clear what was you question. I thought you wanted to send the dictionary as part of the exception